# What is the precise definition of the "positive/ negative side" of a straight line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

In the link below, it is stated that for a point $P(x_1,y_1)$ and an equation of a straight line $ax+by+c=0,$ if $ax_1 +by_1 +c >0$ then the side the point $P$ is on is called the positive side [sides of a straight line](https://www.math-only-math.com/position-of-a-point-relative-to-a-line.html#:%7E:text=If%20ax1%2B%20by1,is%20called%20its%20negative%20side.)

Here, my confusion is that I can simply multiply the equation of the straight line by minus 1 and that would give me $(-a)x+ (-b)y+ (-c)=0$ which represents the same line. Now, if I plug in $x_1$ and $y_1$ into this equation, the result will be negative. Hence the side containing the point $P$ would be the negative side.

Right now, I am really confused. Could anyone clarify?

Comment: I don't know how to format, sorry

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: You are correct.  It's the same problem as saying which is the left side of the line; it depends on which way you are facing.  The important thing is that it allows us to tell when points are different sides of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the equivalent is $(-a)x+(-b)y+(-c)=0.$ You forgot $-c.$

But you are correct, the usage of the term “positive side” in this sense is more about the choice of $a,b,c$ than just the set of points in the line. Given a line, you can think of the choice $a,b,c$ as picking an “orientation” for the line, deciding which side of the line is considered positive and which side is negative.

Think of yourself on a plane, and stick your arms out, pointing left and right. That determines a line. Now which direction you are facing is an orientation. You’d get the same line if you turned completely around. Now the two sides of the line are “front and back.”

Similarly, an orientation of a line can be thought of as assigning directions “left” and “right” to a line.

---

There is no good “continuous” way to assign a single orientation for every line.

In such an assignment, a small rotation would only change the “sides” of a few other points, but a rotation of $180^\circ$ would then swap the positive and negative sides.

So there is no good “natural” meaning to “positive and negative sides of a line.”